# Distribute Points on instanced geometry

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to instance a leaf on my instanced stems. But it only shows the stems.
Is the geometry output of the Point Instance node not treated as full normal geometry?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you include the leaves inside the stem object. You can use the same technique twice. You should use a random seed on the leaves, otherwise all the stems have the same leaves. Distribute this stem-leave object on the floor. This should work.

Comment: yes that`s what I did but there was no option to assign a random seed per stem instance

Comment: Mmm... Maybe you could use the object's location as a seed? I know that the geometry nodes are still under heavy development, so I rackon it will be a thing of the future. Either way, you could always make 3 or 4 stems with leaves and randomly spread these on your plane.

Comment: The location as seed did not work... I will go the long route and just create a batch of stems thanks...

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is: add a "Realized Instance" node then "Distribute Points on Faces" then "Instance on Points". This worked for me on Blender 3.0.